# 'swiper/css/freemode'; can't be found when trying to import Swiper

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I'm trying to use Swiper in my React app and have seen that this is a common issue that Swiper won't work right due to a version upgrade or something. This is my current code:

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import { FreeMode } from "swiper";

import 'swiper/swiper.min.css';
import 'swiper/css/freemode';
```

I had to replace 'swiper/css' with 'swiper.min.css' to get the errors to stop for that one, but trying to import swiper/css/freemode isn't working. I can't find any solutions that help. Does anyone know what I need to change it to so it works?

One site shows that apparently this works, but it doesn't for me and still gives an error:

```
import 'swiper/modules/free-mode/free-mode.min.css';
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, another in my long run of newbie mistakes, but in case anyone else ever has the same issue..

I merely forgot to put the dash in-between 'free-mode'